# When is it possible to replace "of genitive" structure with prenominal modification?

Tags: grammar, attributive-nouns, genitive-construction

As far as I know, many phrases consisting of "of genitive" structure can be replaced with phrases involving nouns modified by attributive nouns, for example,

- *member of community* → *community member*
- *delivery of mail* → *mail delivery*
- ...

Now, I wonder whether it is **always** possible to convert "of genitive" phrases to prenominal modification phrases. If not, to what kinds of "of genitive" phrases can such a conversion be applied?

Comment: **Right of way** doesn't become way right. It will always depend on the individual example.

Comment: What @RonaldSole said. Another example - it's only ever *that time of the month*, never *that month time*. Conversely, we only give Christmas presents, never presents of Christmas.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Repost as an answer and I'll +1 it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not always the case that "X of Y" can be converted into "Y X" with little or no change of meaning. In some cases one form or the other is simply not used. This is a matter of historical accident; to the best of my understanding there is no general rule. In some cases one form or the other is in effect an idiom.

Some examples:

- "Right of way" is a common phrase, but "way right" is unusual, and if it has a meaning at all, it is not the same one.
- "Queen of Hearts" has several meanings and a rich context, partly through its well-known use in *Alice in Wonderland* and in a number of popular songs. "Heart queen" is used in card games, particularly bridge, for the actual card, but carries none of the wider meaning
- "Time of day" means a specified hour. "Day time" means the sunlit hours, a quite different thing.
- "Member of community" is awkward if not incorrect. It should be "member of a community" or "member of the community' dependent on context. But "community member" does not require an article before "community"
- "Master of Balliol" is a specific office at Balliol College, Oxford. But "Balliol Master" could be any of the faculty members (Dons) at the College, if it mans anything.
- More generally "Master of X" where X is the name of an estate or institution, generally is a specific office or position, while  "X Master" is not.
- "Doctor of Laws" is an academic degree. "Law doctor" is a person who seeks to amend a law, or to manipulate or evade it.
- "Play Doctor" is a person consulted to improve a play thought to be not written well, while "Doctor of Plays" is not used at all.
- When the second element is a place name, such as "Timon of Athens", "Mary of York", "Saul of Tarsus", or "Richard of England" the reversed from simply does not work: "York Mary" or "England Richard" have no clear meaning.
- "The Sultan of Swat" was a nickname for baseball player Babe Ruth. "Swat Sultan" has no clear meaning.

In short, such a conversion may or may not work, depending on the particular phrase involved.